# iterated square roots convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I suspect that
$$
\forall (x, a) \in \mathbb{N}_*^2,\ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{\dots \sqrt{x + a}}}}}}_k > \frac{x}{2}
$$
However, I have no  idea how to prove it.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, I am just wondering to what value it converges with respect to $x$ and $a$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio well not really. You just told me that it cannot converge to a negative value, which I am already aware of.

Comment: @Mechap assuming $x,a$ are positive, it'll always converge to $1$. Did you instead mean something like $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\cdots \sqrt{x+a}}}}$$ That might be more interesting.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I have just realized that I may have miswritten the definition of the sequence. We add $+x$ at each step, not only at the last square root. I'm not sure how to write it in standard notation, though.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant sorry

Comment: As you've rewritten it, I don't think the limit will depend on the value of $a$ at all; $x$ it going to be more a part of the calculation. But I think that the direction of the limit *might* depend on $a$. Eventually you'll find some value $b$ for which $b = \sqrt{x+b}$, which should be the limit. That solves to $b^2-b=x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$f(x)=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{\dots \sqrt{x + a}}}}}}_k$$
Assuming that $f(x)$ converges,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sqrt{x+f(x)}\\
\left\{f(x)\right\}^2&-f(x)-x=0\\
f(x)&=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}
\end{align}
And then
$$f(x)\le\frac x2\quad(x\ge6)$$

Comment: Maybe you can prove the iteration is a contraction to show it converges to the fixed point.

Comment: @ShawSa $f(x)$ does converge to $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$. I don't know why the OP got the incorrect conclusion that $f(x) > x/2$.

Comment: I agree with you. Your proof said "assuming that $f(x)$ converges..." and then you go on to find a fixed point of the iteration. I'm saying you can prove this part using the Banach Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: @ShawSa Ah I see. I misread 'contraction' as 'contradiction'. I haven't heard of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem before. Thank you for letting me know it.